# What does a provider class mean in the .NET world?

Tags: .net, provider

There are many classes having this `provider` suffix. (Data,membership,modelmetadata,...).

When should be a class called as a provider class ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Providers mostly are between your logic and data stores of any kind (database, xml, etc.). MSDN mentions:

> Providers abstract storage media in much the same way that device drivers abstract hardware devices.

For more information: [Microsoft ASP.NET 2.0 Providers: Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx)

**For example:**
In stead of working with a database or XML, you want to work with flat file storage on a disk somewhere within your network. To manage this you build a custom provider and use it within your logic to save the data.

Comment: The reason they exist is to be replaced. Like I write a web application now that will map authentication and authorization to an application internal user store - and I can hook taht nicely into the provider model.

Answer (score 7):

Here is description of provider pattern from MS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx):

> The pattern itself is exceedingly
>   simple and is given the name
>   "provider" since it provides the
>   functionality for an API. Defined, a
>   provider is simply a contract between
>   an API and the Business Logic/Data
>   Abstraction Layer. The provider is the
>   implementation of the API separate
>   from the API itself. For example, the
>   new Whidbey Membership feature has a
>   static method called
>   Membership.ValidateUser(). The
>   Membership class itself contains no
>   business logic; instead it simply
>   forwards this call to the configured
>   provider. It is the responsibility of
>   the provider class to contain the
>   implementation for that method,
>   calling whatever Business Logic Layer
>   (BLL) or Data Access Layer (DAL) is
>   necessary.
>
> There are some rules for how a
>   provider behaves. A provider
>   implementation must derive from an
>   abstract base class, which is used to
>   define a contract for a particular
>   feature. For example, to create a
>   membership provider for Oracle, you
>   create a new class
>   OracleMembershipProvider, which
>   derives from MembershipProviderBase.
>   The feature base class, for example,
>   MembershipProviderBase, in turn
>   derives from a common ProviderBase
>   base class. The ProviderBase class is
>   used to mark implementers as a
>   provider and forces the implementation
>   of a required method and property
>   common to all providers. Figure 4
>   gives an example of the inheritance
>   chain.

Comment: may I know the reason why they did not use interface here? like IProvider